# Memory footprint of Javascript versus c# and Java

Tags: javascript, java, c#, dynamic, static

Since javascript assumes and allots 64bits to every number type does it mean javascript runtimes(and other dynamically typed language) use more memory than static typed language implementations like c# and java.

Comment: You can't just take and compare memory management for those two languages, c# is compiled language and is executed in a virtual machine, javascript is not compiled and its engine is within the browser, so different browsers, different engines, different performance. If I continue, the answer will be too broad.

Comment: No. It just means that JavaScript uses more memory _for those specific types_ than .NET (any language) or the Java runtime. You cannot generalize to all dynamic, nor all statically-typed, languages

Comment: Don't forget to add in the memory overhead of the environment process in which JS typically is hosted - the _web browser_.  Unless you are running headless